# Get the difference in weeks, data stored as YYYYWW in TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, datediff

I have customer_since stored as `YYYYWW` i.e., 201852.

The below script is what I have been using to work out the difference, however when I have this situation of 201901 - 201852, it gives 48 instead of 1.
is there mod function or something that can be incorporated here to resolve the issue?

```
CAST(CONCAT (DATEPART(YEAR, DATEADD(MONTH, + 9, GETDATE()))
, RIGHT('0' + RTRIM(DATEPART(WEEK, DATEADD(MONTH, - 3, GETDATE()))+1),2)
) AS INT) - a.customer_since AS Customer_since
```

Comment: If you would have stored the dates properly (as Date data type) you wouldn't have any problem using `DateDiff(Week, Date1, Date2)`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following template to get the first (or the last) date of a given year and week. Then having valid date times, simply use [DATEDIFF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) as it has built in functionality to get difference in weeks:

```
DECLARE @WeekNo int= 52
DECLARE @Year int=2018

SELECT DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0)) AS WeekStart,
       DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))-1 AS WeekEnd

GO

DECLARE @WeekNo int= 1
DECLARE @Year int=2019


SELECT DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo-1,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0)) AS WeekStart,
       DATEADD(wk,@WeekNo,DATEADD(yy,@Year-1900,0))-1 AS WeekEnd

GO

SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, '2018-12-24 00:00:00.000', '2019-01-01 00:00:00.000')
```

In one statement:

```
DECLARE @Input01 VARCHAR(6) = '201852' 
       ,@Input02 VARCHAR(6) = '201901'

SELECT DATEDIFF(WEEK, DATEADD(WEEK, RIGHT(@Input01, 2)-1,DATEADD(YEAR,LEFT(@Input01, 4)-1900,0)), DATEADD(WEEK,RIGHT(@Input02, 2)-1,DATEADD(YEAR,LEFT(@Input02, 4)-1900,0)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function which will accept the date string('201852') and will return a date like `Create Function Todate(@dt varchar(100))
returns Date
Begin
Declare @wk int=(Select RIGHT(@dt,2))

return (Select Dateadd(WK, @wk, cast(LEFT(@dt,4) as date)))
End`

Now all you have to do is pass the date string in the function and find a DATEDIFF with start and End date